# \AddToShipoutPictureFG* ignoring the \@title macro

Tags: titles, eso-pic

I'm trying to make a colored box that takes all the paper width and is placed at (0, 0) on the page. So I tried to use `eso-pic`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
    \newpage \null \vskip .7em\begin{center}\let \footnote \thanks { \Huge \@title \par }\vskip 1.5em{\large \lineskip .5em\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end{tabular}\par \vskip.5em}\end{center}\par \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\title{The actual title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
        \raisebox{-\height}{%
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\paperwidth,colupper=white,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,bottom=4em,top=4em,fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\centering\Large]%
                \Huge Some Title
            \end{tcolorbox}%
        }%
    }%
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This works perfectly:
[image]

Now, I'm trying to put this in my `\@maketitle` redefinition. So I tried:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{
    \newpage \null \vskip .7em\begin{center}\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
        \AtPageUpperLeft{%
            \raisebox{-\height}{%
                \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\paperwidth,colupper=white,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,bottom=4em,top=4em,fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\centering\Large]%
                    \Huge \@title Test
                \end{tcolorbox}%
            }%
        }%
    }\let \footnote \thanks{\large \lineskip .5em\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end{tabular}\par \vskip.5em}\end{center}\par \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\title{The actual title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But it's ignoring the `\@title` macro:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `\maketitle` (within the [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co) class). While it does call `\@maketitle` (and therefore your (re)definition), it also clears `\@title` (amongst others) at the end of `\maketitle`. Why is this important? Well, you are setting/printing the title during page shipout (with [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s `\AddToShipoutPictureFG`), not immediately. So by the time you're setting the title, `\@title` doesn't contain the actual title anymore (in fact, it's set to `\relax`).

How do you get around this? You can store `\@title` inside another macro (say, `\@temptitle`) that you use when setting the title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \global\let\@temptitle\@title% Make \@title available for use later as \@temptitle
  \newpage \null \vskip .7em\begin{center}\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{%
      \raisebox{-\height}{%
        \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\paperwidth,colupper=white,colback=black,colframe=black,arc=0mm,bottom=4em,top=4em,fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries\centering\Large]%
          \Huge \@temptitle
        \end{tcolorbox}%
      }%
    }%
  }\let \footnote \thanks{\large \lineskip .5em\begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end{tabular}\par \vskip.5em}\end{center}\par \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\title{The actual title}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```